# How long does a haunt stay neutralized?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, undead, traps

How long since been reduced to 0 hp does a haunt stay neutralized?

I tried reading upon the rules multiple times, but failed to see the part where it says this specifically.

Answer (score 5):

Per the [Elements of a Haunt](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/haunts/#Elements_of_a_Haunt) section of the rules:

> **Reset:** This is the amount of time that must pass before a haunt can attempt to reset. Until it is destroyed, a haunt can reset after this period by succeeding on a DC 10 caster level check—failure indicates the haunt must wait that amount of time again before making another attempt |to reset.

| Reset Time | CR Modifier |
| --- | --- |
| 1 minute | +2 |
| 1 hour | +1 |
| 1 day | +0 |
| 1 week | -1 |

Comment: so "reset" actually does mean that the hit points return as well?